# Replace symbols in many columns in one update

Tags: sql-server

I have many update statements in my SQL script:

```
UPDATE DBO.Products SET products_fullTextSearch = REPLACE(products_fullTextSearch, ' ', '')
UPDATE DBO.Products SET products_fullTextSearch = REPLACE(products_fullTextSearch, '°', '')
UPDATE DBO.Products SET products_fullTextSearch = REPLACE(products_fullTextSearch, '±', '')
UPDATE DBO.Products SET products_fullTextSearch = REPLACE(products_fullTextSearch, '\', '')
UPDATE DBO.Products SET products_fullTextSearch = REPLACE(products_fullTextSearch, '/', '')
..............................
etc
```

How could I do it in one UPDATE statement?

Comment: Use nested `REPLACE`: `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(...`

Comment: May you provide some code example for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing nested `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE DBO.Products 
    SET products_fullTextSearch = 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(products_fullTextSearch, ' ', ''),'°', ''),
                '±', ''
            ),
            '\', ''
        ),
    '/', ''
    )
```

Comment: This is the way I do it :).

Comment: The original poster *did* imply (by use of a long ...................... sequence of periods) that he has many of these to do though, possibly hundreds. That's gonna get pretty big and *very* ugly very quickly. See my answer about creating a custom function for a much cleaner way of having the database do the same thing..

Comment: If he knows what characters are to be replaced,  then it's worth it. This is faster than using a `WHILE` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In some other RDBMS, the TRANSLATE function could do the brunt of this work but alas SQL Server has no TRANSLATE equivalent. It hasn't stopped people wanting it..

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Translate 
 (
 @Input AS VarChar(1000),
 @Find AS VarChar(100),
 @Replace AS VarChar(100)
 )
 RETURNS VarChar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @i AS TinyInt

 SELECT @i = 1

 WHILE @i <= LEN(@Find) BEGIN

  SELECT @Input = REPLACE(@Input, SUBSTRING(@Find, @i, 1), SUBSTRING(@Replace, @i, 1))
  SELECT @i = @i + 1

 END
 RETURN @Input
END
GO

DECLARE @String AS VarChar(1000)

SELECT @String = 'pootle_flump'
SELECT @String = dbo.Translate(@String, 'pt', 'xz')

PRINT  @String
```

Source: http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1216565-Oracle-Translate-function-equivalent-in-SQL-Server

You'd use it like this:

```
UPDATE DBO.Products 
SET products_fullTextSearch = REPLACE(dbo.Translate(products_fullTextSearch, '°±\/', '    '), ' ', '')
```

How it works:

First, a TRANSLATE will turn 4 characters that you don't want, into spaces (which is also a character you don't want)

Immediately after, REPLACE will turn all the spaces into nothing

The beauty of translate is that it's easy to extend the number of characters to swap. Translate takes the first character of the "find" string and replaces it with the first character in the "replace" string. Then it moves on to the second character (in both find and replace)

The following command:

```
Translate(input_text, 'abcd', '1234')
```

Would make these amendments:

```
'cat' -> '31t'
'dog' -> '4og'
'ffeeddccbbaa' -> 'ffee44332211'
```

Actually, there's no need for the REPLACE, because you can exploit a "quirk" in the way substring will do its job, by providing a zero length string for the "replace" argument:

```
UPDATE DBO.Products 
SET products_fullTextSearch = dbo.Translate(products_fullTextSearch, '°±\/ ', '')
```

Because the function will attempt to find a single character in the "replacement" string argument for every character in the "find" string, and because there are no characters in the "replacement", the substring will always return null(or a zero length string) as the replacement character, which means the characters in the "find" string will each be replaced with (nothing)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've written another function which return word only if it consists of [a-z0-9]) And insert this selection into table)